# How do I change the directory that a batch file will output text to?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a log that a user will create in a batch file, as a small little game, but I can't seem to get the correct directory of the file down. I want to write to this directory:

```
BatchfileandFolder\subfolder1\subfolder2\ThedataisHere.txt
```

This is the code I have (I really don't know what I am doing)

```
Echo Write a piece of text here  
set /p UserData=
>>\subfolder1\subfolder2\"ThedataisHere.txt" echo %UserData%
```

It is essential trying to dig deeper into the directory, but I don't know the exact command, and the help menu for CD, and PATH on the cmd.exe promt don't really help me that much.

Thank you for real human contact, speaking real English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "logfile=u:\sub folder1\sub folder2\ThedataisHere.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%logfile%") DO MD "%%~dpa"
Echo Write a piece of text here  
set /p UserData=
>>"%logfile%" echo %UserData%

GOTO :EOF
```

This method uses a variable `logfile` so that you aren't forever typing out the name (and avoid the pain if you want to change the names or directories, and the method allows you yo use multiple logfiles easily if you want)

I've deliberately used `spaces in directory names` to prove the method. The directory gets created immediately after the logfile name is set

- append `2>nul` to the `md` instruction line to suppress the `directory already exists` message

From there, simply use `>>"%logfile%"` to create the log. The quotes are not required if the filename doesn't contain separators like spaces.

Note that if the first character of the directory specified is `\` then the directory is relative to the root, but if it is not then the directory is relative to the current directory on the destination drive. `u:` is a drive specifier, not a directoryname; I use `u:` as my test drive. Your choice is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the directory structure already exists, it's pretty simple:

```
@echo off
set /p UserData=Write some text here: 
@echo %UserData% >> "subfolder1\subfolder2\TheDataIsHere.txt"
```

If it doesn't exist already, you have to create it first (tested on Win7 64 bit):

```
@echo off
if not exist "subfolder1" md "subfolder1"
if not exist "subfolder1\subfolder2" md "subfolder1\subfolder2"
set /p UserData=Write some text here: 
@echo %UserData% >> "subfolder1\subfolder2\TheDataIsHere.txt"
```

Comment: It is not necessary to individually create each directory: "If Command Extensions are enabled... MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed".

Answer (score 1):

Although your description is ample, some important points are missing. It is obvious that you know "How to change the directory that a batch file will output text to", because you use the `>> \subfolder\...` notation, so this is *not* your problem. I can only guess that you want to know "How to get the directory where a batch file is located", so you can write to a log file placed two levels below *that* directory. If this is your problem, then you may use the `%~P0` notation, that represent the path of the batch file; that is:

```
>> "%~P0subfolder1\subfolder2\ThedataisHere.txt" echo %UserData%
```

Note that the value returned by `%~P0` ends in a backslash, so `%~P0` must *not* be separated by an additional backslash from `subfolder1`; also note that the quotes must enclose the *whole* path of the file.

If this is not what you want, please carefully describe your real problem. Anyway, try to be clearer in future questions.